# SugarCRM won't show The Releases Module tab

Tags: php, module, sugarcrm, suitecrm

There is a Bugs Module in SugarCRM/SuiteCRM which editview has fields "Found in release" and "Fixed in release". By default they both empty. User should add versions through the module Releases.

But here I have a problem.

1. I use SuiteCRM 7.02 (SugarCRM fork) and login as admin user (all access).
2. I have no "Releases" tab on the tab's panel.
3. There is no Releases  module available at the Admin - Display Modules and Subpanels page  (it's not listed in the list Displayed/Hidden  Modules)
4. There was no bug_release_dom DropDownList so I have  created it.
5. Module available by direct URL  /suitecrm/index.php?module=Releases and works correct.

**How can I enable Release module tab?**

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the link manually to your admin page and open a ticket ([report issue](https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/issues)).

To archive this add a file in custom/Extension/modules/Administration/ext/Release.php or by adding this to your manifest.php if you want a installable patch:
`'administration' =>
    array(
        array(
            'from' => '<basepath>/Release.php',
            'to' => 'modules/Administration/Release.php',
        ),
    ),`

This goes into the file Release.php:

`$admin_option_defs = array();
$admin_option_defs['Administration'] = array(
    'release_config' => array(
        'Release',
        'LBL_MANAGE_RELEASES',
        'LBL_RELEASE',
        './index.php?module=Releases&action=index'
        ),
);
$admin_group_header[] = array(
    'LBL_RELEASE',
    '',
    false,
    $admin_option_defs,
    ''
);`

The labels should still be there so it should work after a repair and rebuild